# IE filter gradient not showing wrong colors

Tags: css

I have some link buttons that I'm using CSS3 gradient code that I generated from Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator. It is working great except for IE7-9 (not worrying about IE6). Instead of the nice mid-gray to dark gray it is showing a blue to black gradient. The code being used is:

```
background: #666666; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #666666 0%, #141414 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#666666), color-stop(100%,#141414)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #666666 0%,#141414 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #666666 0%,#141414 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #666666 0%,#141414 100%); /* IE10+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#666666', endColorstr='#141414',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
background: linear-gradient(top, #666666 0%,#141414 100%); /* W3C */
```

To see what it is rendering like: http://bradmccullough.com.w.jaijaz.co.nz/

I have noticed that altering the display css element changes it but can't put my finger on what exactly is going on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are using the shorthand color for gray in your CSS.  Make sure you use #666666.  Looking at the source of the stylesheet, for the IE filter, you're using #666 (although in your post above you have it right).

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. I hadn't realised my CMS replaced shorthand versions of hex colors when it is combining and compressing stylesheet. Great spotting.

Comment: Thank you.  I was having the same problem because I had used #fff and not #ffffff.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem recently. We identified that running CSS minify on the CSS files would shorten '#666666' to '#666', resulting in IE8 not being able to render the correct colour value within the 'filter' property. The only alternative was to define the colour as 'white' (our problem was with '#ffffff') or tweaking the colour slightly, i.e. '#fffffe' to prevent it from being written in shorthand.